# iOS swift Firebase storage downloading large files background issue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download large video files from Firebase Storage, and whereas I've been searching whole web I didn't find any good solution to my issue, while I'm continously upgrade Firebase versions.

So, I've added the "Background fetch" and "Background processing" capabilities to my project, and added the "Permitted background task scheduler identifiers" item in info.plist file with "GTMSessionFetcher-firebasestorage.googleapis.com", but when I'm downloading these files I got the error:

> Background Task 61 ("GTMSessionFetcher-firebasestorage.googleapis.com"), was created over 30 seconds ago. In applications running in the background, this creates a risk of termination. Remember to call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:) for your task in a timely manner to avoid this.

Here is my example code:

```
for urlString in [ ... ] {
  DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    
    let ref = self.storage.reference(forURL: urlString)

    // Download to the local filesystem
    ref.write(toFile: fileURL) { _, error in

      if let error = error {
        print(value: error, type: .error)
        onDemand(.failure(error))
      } else {
        onDemand(.success(true))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried to limit the number of threads downloading using semaphore to limit the number of threads created, but without no success.
Not settings QoS result in the same errors.

These warnings prevent me from publishing my app to the store.

Have you any suggestion ?

Comment: You should look up the documentation for Background fetch and Background processing, DispatchQueue is a back ground thread but those refer to the app being in the background, not a threading issue they work quite differently

Comment: Additionnaly, I want to say that theses fetches are ran at login, while app is in foreground. So you think, that I should care about this only if my app goes to background ? I will check these capabilities as in further development, we want to download in background new assets

Comment: Ho you are right. I've checked these capabilities on Apple's doc, and they are used only when app is in background (fetching short data) or device is idle (fetching large data to update the app). So you are right, these capabilities are no use at that point, as I fetch the videos while app is in foreground (for now). Do you think these warnings are notified because the Firebase method is used in background (by settings its id in info.plist, or internally in method code)

Comment: That sounds like there is an actual BackgroundTask running (not background thread) but the id is something with Google so I am not sure what is triggering it. I would research the error itself there is likely something else going on not related to this code at all. Maybe even a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of this answer, Apple still allows limited time to perform background work. This limited time may not be enough to download the large files you mentioned. You should read the [Background Strategies for Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/choosing_background_strategies_for_your_app) documentation to decide how you want to handle this limitation. I believe this is why your download task gets killed by the system and why you see that error. The system is essentially notifying you as a courtesy that OS is killing the background task you initiated and you should complete the task and call `UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:)` within the allotted time (generally around 30 seconds).

One possibility is to defer this activity to a later time using  [BGProcessingTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgprocessingtask) APIs. This background activity is specifically designed to process long-duration activities; however, the system decides when to execute them. You have to schedule this long-duration task using [BGTaskScheduler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskscheduler) API.

The other possibility is to ask the user explicitly through your app's UX is to keep the app on the foreground. As long as your app stays on the foreground, the task to download the large file should not be killed.

**Update based on new information from the PO**

TL;DR: You need to add a pre-processor macro definition to your target `GTM_BACKGROUND_TASK_FETCHING = 0` to force Firebase storage to perform the download on the foreground. Here is why:

I did some digging on Firebase Storage source code. As of version 10,  `StorageReference` class that you use to perform the download operation above appears to be scheduling the download task in the background no matter what. And it looks like if you schedule an operation to run in the background, you have to finish it within the allotted time even if your app is on the foreground. Ideally, StorageReference exposes a setting for the developer to override this functionality.
This can be actually done if `StorageReference` class makes `fetcherService` property public. It is currently private:

[image]

If you keep digging further `GTMSessionFetcherService` actually allows this background task to be overridden by a property called `skipBackgroundTask`. See screenshots:

[image: GTMSessionFetcherService.skipBackgroundTask property]

[image: GTMSessionFetcherService pre-processor macro]

It looks like if you define a pre-processor macro with the value `GTM_BACKGROUND_TASK_FETCHING = 0`, StorageReference should skip scheduling the task as a background process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, my app is still in foreground during the whole process, and I feel like it's inside Firebase framework but I don't have any options to play with to customize process.

Comment: I updated my answer based on this information.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for these additional informations, which are not well documented. I think that it will accelerate my download rate if tasks are not ran in background and increase response time of my app. I will check later for background download when using the application and cloud database is updated.